# Not Provide count has reached 80%! But what about remaining 20?

Tags: google-analytics

I am updated with all not-provided reasons as Google has encrypted their all searches, but here is the little question banging again and again in my head. That if all search results has encrypted with HTTPS protocol then how did Google analytics still able to track some of  (20%) organic keywords details?

I means their still some keywords appreading in my organic keywords section. So how did Google analytics track or bypass that HTTPS thing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming (seems better fit for webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

Google enforces the HTTPS protocol only on Signed-In users, so users that are not signed in have the ability to search through HTTP and not HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Or Ziberman but that is not the case anymore. Google recently announced that all searches has encrypted with Secure HTTPS protocol. Not matter whether you logged in or not, using incognito or any other specification.